# Variable Framerate into Constant Avconv

Tags: video, avconv

I want to change a video with variable framerate into constant. I don't wanna mess up with any other part of the video except making constant the framerate.

I'm using:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -codec copy -codec:a mp3 -r 30 output.mp4
```

At the end, it gives me this command line response:

```
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 1794, current: 1794; changing to 1795. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame= 1272 fps=196 q=-1.0 Lsize=  378144kB time=42.77 bitrate=72423.5kbits/s    
video:287196kB audio:670kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 31.361036%
```

I can play the output.mp4 nicely (audio video sync is fine). However, when I checked the mediainfo of the output.mp4 it says framerate is

```
Frame rate : 90 000.000 fps
```

What happened? How can I force the output to be in 30 or 25 fps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it fixed via:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -c:v h264 -crf 25 -c:a mp3 -r 30 output.mp4
```

The `-crf number` part did the work. Choose a number that works for you as the lower it comes, the more bitrates are used.

I tried '5' and got somewhere 250k bitrates.